# VBA select a range of cells based on a value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select a range of cells in VBA in which last cell selected is based on value of another cell.
I want to select cells O4 to "The cell vale of M4 (as shown in attached photo)".

I tried -

```
Sub Macro5()

    Range("O4:O22").Select

    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "x"

End Sub
```

But I want O22 to be variable based on the value in cell "M4".

Comment: Your 'attached photo' is missing?

Comment: Do you need to `Select` it (which is not recmended) or assign the formula to it? You can simply just use 1 line `Range("O4:" & Range("M4").Value).FormulaR1C1 = "x"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub Macro5()

    Range("O4:" & Range("M4")).Select

    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "x"

End Sub
```